# Adding a scroll bar in css content accordion

Tags: html, css

I'm following this tutorial on how to code a content accordion:
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-content-accordion/

How could I add infinite content to each section with a scroll bar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just use the x and y overflow properties to make it scrollable. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp

For instance, you'd do something like this with the css:

```
section {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: combine this solution with a max-height and you are all set

Comment: Is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y a better documentation reference? I'll edit my answer to use that instead.

Comment: This worked:

section { display: block; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden;}